# Can't host site with Firebase

Tags: firebase, web, host, firebase-hosting

I have problem with deploying site to host.

When I complete all steps and enter to the hosted site it says:

[image]

My steps:

npm run build and it created build folder

firebase init , select hosting ,

What do you want to use as your public directory? build

Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes

File build/index.html already exists. Overwrite? No

and then finally firebase deploy

Comment: You've configured Firebase to deploy the `build` directory, and it seems like that directory does not contain your public web site data.

Comment: As said, make sure `build/index.html` contains _your_ website's content. Make sure you are deploying to the correct project: (1) if `.firebaserc` exists in your directory, make sure it contains the correct project name, (2) use the `--project <project_name>` flag on `firebase deploy`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your files to the build directory before deploying